# can I use other distro than Arago for building an image with meta-ti for yocto linux?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, texas-instruments, yocto-layer

I am trying to build EWAOL image for TDA4VM using distro as EWAOL, but it is giving me override errors like, "Overrides could not be expanded into a stable state after 5 iterations, overrides must be being referenced by other overridden variables in some recursive fashion. Please provide your configuration to bitbake-devel so we can laugh".
When I use distro as arago, the image is generated but device is not booting. Can you provide me some insights on this? 
Can I build a Yocto image using meta-ti without distro as arago?

To build the image with kas I had created a kas file

```
header:
  version: 10

repos:
  meta-ti:
    url: git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-ti
    path: layers/meta-ti
    refspec: kirkstone
    layers:
      meta-ti-bsp:
      meta-ti-extras:
    
  
  meta-arm:
    url: https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/meta-arm
    path: layers/meta-arm
    refspec: kirkstone
    layers:
      meta-arm: included
      meta-arm-bsp: included
      meta-arm-toolchain: included
  
  meta-openembedded:
    url: https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded.git
    path: layers/meta-openembedded
    refspec: kirkstone
    layers:
      meta-oe: included
      meta-networking: included
      meta-python: included
      
  meta-arago:
    url: git://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-arago
    refspec: kirkstone
    path: layers/meta-arago
    layers:
      meta-arago-distro:
      meta-arago-extras:
      
  meta-qt5:
    url: https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5.git
    refspec: kirkstone
    path: layers/meta-qt5
    layers:
      .:

machine: j721e-evm
distro: ewaol
local_conf_header:
    meta-custom: |
```

and integrated it with [meta-ewaol-machine](https://gitlab.com/soafee/ewaol/meta-ewaol-machine), but it is giving me error as stated above.

I am looking to get the image develop and working on my ti-TDA4VM board.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build an image for a TI device without using Arago. For example, you can use Poky and make slight adjustments to the [Yocto Quick Build](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html).

You can browse the [OpenEmbedded Layer Index](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layers/) to try and find the machine you wish to support, for example TI provides support for the `TI J721e EVM` in  kirkstone in `meta-ti-bsp`. So with `bitbake-layers add-layer` you can add in the TI layer, you may have to add in required layers such as `meta-arm`.

So in your build/conf/local.conf you can specify the machine

```
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS += "kernel-modules"
MACHINE ??= "j721e-evm"
```

And you can use bitbake to make a basic image such as `core-image-weston` which provides a simple GUI image. It will be found in `build/tmp/deploy/images/<machine>`.

For example building for the `am57xx-evm` machine for the `core-image-weston` resulted in a `core-image-weston-am57xx-evm-20230503092800.rootfs.wic.xz` file which can be flashed onto an SD card with a tool such as [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher). Which should populate the SD card with both a root and boot partition.

I haven't used meta-EWAOL, but on your link it mentions:

> NOTE, EWAOL Kirkstone has not yet been released, this will not work for you yet

Also I am not familiar with `kas` but my recommendation would be to create a simple image with Yocto to see if you can get the bootloader working and the kernel booted. The TI SDK should mention a way to get output from the board when booting, in  my experience you will have to plug in a USB device and use something like `picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0` in Linux or [Tera Term](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/index.html.en) in Windows to see if you can get the bootloader output.

The above has all been based on booting from an SD card. If there is still no output you might have to check if you have set the switch on the board to boot from an SD card. You can also check the TI provided image from their SDK to see if that boots up, or ask on the TI forums for more advice. For example I have had an issue with the `SK-AM68` where it would only boot with `tiboot3-j721s2-hs-fs-evm.bin` and not `tiboot3-j721s2-hs-fs-evm.bin`, [see more here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors-group/processors/f/processors-forum/1213381/sk-am68-the-board-arrived-dead).

Once you have a basic image working you can experiment with adding in other layers and other configurations.